# In Google Search Google Takes Meta Description or Products Description?

Tags: magento-1.9, google

What google takes, sometimes my meta description shown and sometimes products description shown.

Comment: can you please provide example

Comment: If I search my products on Google, in the area of meta description shown my products description, not my meta description. Some other products meta description area shown my product meta description, not products description.

Comment: can you provide website url and screen shot i will check

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid this has nothing to do with Magento, but with Google itself

https://searchengineland.com/google-officially-increases-length-snippets-search-results-287596

> Some webmasters and SEOs may consider updating their meta descriptions, but I don’t believe Google would recommend doing so. The snippets are more often dynamically generated based on the user query and content found in both the meta description and the content visible on the page. If Google is going to go with a longer snippet, it likely will pull that content from the page